# Create a new column with max values using the identifier column within a pipeline

Tags: r, dplyr, plyr

I am trying to clean up some old code and convert over to "tidy". I am trying to create a new column of data within a pipeline that is the maximum age of individual fish. Let's represent the columns of interest as:

```
fish_1 <- data.frame(year = c(2012,2012,2015,2015,2015,2013,2013,2013,2013,2012,2012,2015,2015,2015),
                     fishid = c('a','a','b','b','b','c','c','c','c','d','d','e','e','e'), # unique identifier for each fish
                     agei = c(1,2,1,2,3,1,2,3,4,1,2,1,2,3))

# which looks like this:
fish_1
   year fishid agei
1  2012      a    1
2  2012      a    2
3  2015      b    1
4  2015      b    2
5  2015      b    3
6  2013      c    1
7  2013      c    2
8  2013      c    3
9  2013      c    4
10 2012      d    1
11 2012      d    2
12 2015      e    1
13 2015      e    2
14 2015      e    3
```

What I'm trying to do is create a new column `agec` that is the maximum age for each individual fish repeated however many number of times is required to fill the rows for each fish.

The desired output would be:

```
fish_2 <- data.frame(year = c(2012,2012,2015,2015,2015,2013,2013,2013,2013,2012,2012,2015,2015,2015),
                     fishid = c('a','a','b','b','b','c','c','c','c','d','d','e','e','e'), # unique identifier for each fish
                     agei = c(1,2,1,2,3,1,2,3,4,1,2,1,2,3),
                     agec = c(2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,2,2,3,3,3))
# Which looks like:
fish_2

   year fishid agei agec
1  2012      a    1    2
2  2012      a    2    2
3  2015      b    1    3
4  2015      b    2    3
5  2015      b    3    3
6  2013      c    1    4
7  2013      c    2    4
8  2013      c    3    4
9  2013      c    4    4
10 2012      d    1    2
11 2012      d    2    2
12 2015      e    1    3
13 2015      e    2    3
14 2015      e    3    3
```

The way I had done this in the past was to use a `plyr::ddply()` call to create a new dataframe and then merge with fish like this:

```
caps = plyr::ddply(fish_1, c('fishid'), plyr::summarize, agec=max(agei))
fish = merge(fish_1, caps, by='fishid')
fish

   fishid year agei agec
1       a 2012    1    2
2       a 2012    2    2
3       b 2015    1    3
4       b 2015    2    3
5       b 2015    3    3
6       c 2013    1    4
7       c 2013    2    4
8       c 2013    3    4
9       c 2013    4    4
10      d 2012    1    2
11      d 2012    2    2
12      e 2015    1    3
13      e 2015    2    3
14      e 2015    3    3
```

I'm hoping someone can help me achieve this data structure concisely within a pipeline. All of the similar questions I have found have been very verbose and not specific to this issue. I am new to using tidyverse but I'm having trouble getting the `group_by()` function (to replace the `ddply()` call) within a pipe, and I'm hoping there is a simpler way.

**UPDATE**

For those interested it appears both answers below are correct. The reason that I struggled was because I was already completing other data manipulations within my pipeline and I tried to complete the formation of the `agec` column within a previous call to `dplyr::mutate()`. You can refer to my comment on @Thomas answer to see the error in my ways. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `dplyr` instead of `plyr`

```r
library(dplyr)

fish_1 %>% 
  group_by(fishid) %>% 
  mutate(agec = max(agei))
```

Comment: Ok, I understand now, in my pipeline I was trying to do all of that within a mutate call...something like   'fish_1%>%  mutate(agec=group_by(fishid)%>%  mutate(agec=max(agei))`  which does not work

Answer (score 2):

You can use `group_by` from `dplyr` to group your fish IDs and then simply call `mutate` (`dplyr` as well) with `max`:

```
fish_1 <- data.frame(year = c(2012,2012,2015,2015,2015,2013,2013,2013,2013,2012,2012,2015,2015,2015),
                     fishid = c('a','a','b','b','b','c','c','c','c','d','d','e','e','e'), # unique identifier for each fish
                     agei = c(1,2,1,2,3,1,2,3,4,1,2,1,2,3))
fish_1 %>% 
  group_by(fishid) %>% 
  mutate(agec = max(agei))
# A tibble: 14 x 4
# Groups:   fishid [5]
    year fishid  agei  agec
   <dbl> <chr>  <dbl> <dbl>
 1  2012 a          1     2
 2  2012 a          2     2
 3  2015 b          1     3
 4  2015 b          2     3
 5  2015 b          3     3
 6  2013 c          1     4
 7  2013 c          2     4
 8  2013 c          3     4
 9  2013 c          4     4
10  2012 d          1     2
11  2012 d          2     2
12  2015 e          1     3
13  2015 e          2     3
14  2015 e          3     3
```

Comment: Is this not the same solution as presented by @Thomas

Comment: yes, we basically posted at the same time

Answer (score 0):

An option with `data.table`

```
library(data.table)   
setDT(fish_1)[, agec := max(agei, na.rm = TRUE), fishid]
```